# Why isn't the git stash unique per branch?

Tags: git, git-stash

I suppose it allows for moving changes from one branch to the next but that's what cherry picking is for and if you're not making a commit of your changes, perhaps you shouldn't be moving them around?

I have on occasion applied the wrong stash at the wrong branch, which left me wondering about this question.

Comment: Git is missing something which allows you to associate uncommitted changes with a branch (or head). This becomes apparent when you have work in progress for more then one branch at a time. As the answers here point out, stash has useful applications based on its characteristics nonetheless. `git stash-here` anyone?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As mentioned, if you want a “per-branch stash,” you really want a new branch forking off from the existing branch.

Also, besides the already mentioned fact that the stash allows you to pull into a branch that you’re working on, it also allows you to *switch* branches before you have committed everything. This is useful not for cherry-picking in the usual sense so much as for cherry-picking *your working copy*.

F.ex., while working on a feature branch, I will often notice minor bugs or cosmetic impurities in the code that aren’t relevant to that branch. Well, I just fix those right away. When time comes to commit, I selectively commit the relevant changes but not the fixes and cosmetics. Instead I stash those, which allows me to switch to my minor-fixes-on-stable branch, where I can then apply the stash and commit each minor fix separately. (Depending on the changes in question, I will also stash some of them yet again, to switch to a different feature branch, where I apply *those*.)

This allows me to go deep into programming mode when I am working, and not worry about proper librarianship of my code. Then when I take a mental break, I can go back and carefully sort my changes into all the right shelves.

If the stash weren’t global, this type of workflow would be far more difficult to do.

Comment: I don't agree with this: `As mentioned, if you want a “per-branch stash,” you really want a new branch forking off from the existing branch.`. In particular, I often switch between two versions of the same program, and running a full `make` takes 10 minutes; being able to stash the built binaries, per-branch, would be very nice. And I certainly don't want the binaries in the log or in a branch.

Comment: Why? (I think you do, you just don’t know it.)

Answer (score 21):

As of Git 1.6, you can now apply stashes to branches using

```
git stash branch name_of_new_branch
```

Git will create the new branch for you, and check it out! For more information, see

- [the git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing#Creating-a-Branch-from-a-Stash)
- `info git-stash` and search on option=`branch`.

I'm guessing you can move stashes around using

```
git stash branch <branch | new_branch> [<stash>]
```

and to see a list of your stashes, use

```
git stash list
```

[Reference](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html)

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware that you could apply stashes to branches, but this appears to be the behavior after all. Having a stash on one branch I checked out another branch and did some work there. As it turned out I needed to stash some of its pending changes also before I could rebase to master. My updated "`gitk --all`" no longer showed my first stash; I thought it might be clobbered. After my work in the second branch was done I then popped that stash.  After that, my updated "`gitk --all`" showed the original stash again.

Answer (score 17):

if you want a "stash" that runs off a branch do something like this to store your changes on a new branch off your current branch.

```
git checkout -b new_stash
git commit -a -m "stashed changes"
```

to undo the stash

```
git reset HEAD^
git branch -d new_stash
```

git stash is especially useful because you can pull changes into a dirty tree, i.e. if you have outstanding edits and want to do a

```
git pull
```

and you can't, you can stash your changes, pull and then apply the stash

```
git stash
git pull
git stash apply
git stash clear
```

hope this helped!

Comment: What if the stuff you're trying to stash is, for example, a bunch of binaries that resulted from running `make` in that branch? (a per-branch stash would save time next time you do an incremental build in that branch, but you certainly don't want to add the binaries to the index)

Answer (score 5):

git-stash is most useful to me to move not-yet-checked-in changes off to a different branch than the one that is currently checked out.

For example - I often find myself doing simple changes on a bug-fixes branch; only to find that a change I'm working on is more complex than I first guessed.  Git-stash is the easiest way to move that set of changes to a different branch.